# Manga with Overpowered boy some #son of a noble?

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

This boy was reincarnated as number (something) son of a noble (meaning, he's not the eldest). But he's powerful in magic. He was able to receive his own title (maybe baron?) and mansion. He made a stuff red dragon as his decoration for the front hall of his mansion. There was a party, he used his knowledge to create glass and utensils that made every noble attending in awe.

Can someone please tell me the name of this manga? I think it also had an anime, but I'm not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Chronicles of an Aristocrat Reborn in Another World](https://sevenseasentertainment.com/series/chronicles-of-an-aristocrat-reborn-in-another-world-manga/) (or rather its [manga adaptation](https://chronicles-of-an-aristocrat.fandom.com/wiki/Manga)).

> Teenager Shiinya Kazuya died while saving young girls from an attacker, only to find himself reincarnated into a world of swords and magic. It was a dream come true! Though he remembers his life and knowledge of Earth, he is now Cain von Silford, the third son of an aristocrat. Being granted the protection of the gods on his fifth birthday turned out to be too much of a good thing for Cain. His stats and boosts are so powerful, he must hide his real abilities to climb the ranks of society as he descends into the darkest dungeons. The ultimate isekai adventure begins as a teen-turned-child is trapped in a beautiful kingdom he didn’t create, but might one day rule!
>
> [image]

Several reviews mention a stuffed red dragon in his house.

Comment: Note that the plotting is almost identical to *Mushoku Tensei: Isekai Ittara Honki Dasu* (Jobless Reincarnation) at least for the first few chapters.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! 

Comment: No problem. Thanks again! 

Comment: @Wanderer - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)